# How to add numbers below 40 in an array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I can't find anyway to get just the numbers below 40 to be added. When I code it this way, it adds up all the numbers in the array.

```
public static int underForty(int[] nums2)   
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for ( int eachValue : nums2)
        {
             if (eachValue < 40)
                {
                   sum = sum + eachValue;
                }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: it seems correct to me. Just for sure, if the input is `{1,2,3,50}`, you expect `6` to be output, right?

Comment: Are you sure the array contains any value(s) above 40?

Comment: It seams there is no logical error in your code. It should work as you expected.

Comment: Let us see the array you are passing to this method.

Comment: @Jiri that's right, but the output ends up being 56 in that case. @ Elliot and Prabhakaran I have values below forty and above forty, and all of the values are being added.

Comment: Show the code of the arrays and how you're passing them to the method

Comment: Are you sure you're running the correct class/code? It would be difficult for the code above to fail to perform as written.

Comment: Your code is 100% correct! btw. consider using Scala: `List(1,2,3,50).filter(_ < 40).sum` ;)

Comment: I found my mistake. I was passing the array to the wrong method in my main method. Oops. It works now. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please validate your assumptions by trying it with some form of "logging".

```
public static int underForty(int[] nums2) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums2)); // print the array contents.
  int sum = 0;
  for (int eachValue : nums2) {
    System.out.println("before Sum is: " + sum); // display the sum before adding.
    if (eachValue < 40) {
      sum = sum + eachValue;
    } else {
      System.out.println("value: " + eachValue + " >= 40"); // display the other(s).
    }
    System.out.println("after Sum is: " + sum); // display the sum after adding.
  }
  return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int sum = underForty(new int[]{1,2,3,50});
  System.out.println("main sum = " + sum);
}
```

When I run the above; I see this output

```
[1, 2, 3, 50]
before Sum is: 0
after Sum is: 1
before Sum is: 1
after Sum is: 3
before Sum is: 3
after Sum is: 6
before Sum is: 6
value: 50 >= 40
after Sum is: 6
main sum = 6
```

Which seems correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Java specifically, but looking at the code, it looks completely valid. I think the problem is probably related to the values in `nums2`. What items are in the array?

I ran this code:

```
public class Foo{

 public static void main(String []args){
    int[] nums2 = {1,49,999,35,46,19,-5};
    int sum = 0;
    for ( int eachValue : nums2)
    {
         if (eachValue < 40)
            {
               sum = sum + eachValue;
            }
    }
    System.out.println( sum );
 }
}
```

And I got 50, the correct answer. So I'm pretty sure your code *is* working.